# Maintain hided the navbar and menubar during a transition

Tags: android, android-animation, transition, fullscreen

I'm developing a children's game. I have an activity with hiding navbar and menubar. At the press of a button the app opens a new activity with a slide transition. In the new activity I hide again the navigation. But during the transition the navigation shows and hides again, the result is terrible.

I want to know if it's posible to make the transition between the two activities maintaining the full screen and without showing navigation bars.

This is the code I use to hide the navigation and make the activity full screen in both activities (and to re-hide in case of lost of focus of the activity):

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            hideSystemUI();
            startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundSoundService.class));
        } else {
            stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundSoundService.class));
        }
    }

private void hideSystemUI() {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
```

And the code to open the new activity at the button press:

```
public void abrirGranja(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, granja.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_izq, R.anim.slide_out_izq);
    }
```

**Thanks a lot!**